# Set background color for QTabBar beyond tabs?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Simple as the question title, I have a QTabWidget and I wanted to set the background color for the QTabBar area, and this is how I do it:

```
ViewTabs->tabBar()->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85,85,85)");
```

I expected this to set the back ground for the whole bar, but instead it sets the background on tabs only as in the attached picture.

[image]

How do I make the background color take effect even beyond the tabs? I'm using QT 5.7 with C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the background color manually in the UI interface by clicking on "palette" in the proprieties. 
It's easier to handle colors this way.